# Area under tangent to a curve.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

The tangent to the graph of the function $y=f(x)$ at the point with abscissa $x=a$ forms with the line $x$-axis an angle $\frac{\pi}{6}$ and at the point with abscissa $x=b$ an angle of  $\frac{\pi}{4}$, then find the value of

$$\int _a^b f^{'}(x)f^{''}(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$$

My attempt:
I did the following substitution:

let $ f^{'}(x)=t$.

$f^{''}(x) \, \mathrm{d}x=\mathrm{d}t$

$$I=\int _a^b t \, \mathrm{d}t=\frac{t^2}{2}=\frac{(f^{'}(x))^2}{2}=\frac{(f^{'}(b))^2}{2}-\frac{(f^{'}(a))^2}{2}=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1\over3}{2}=\frac{1}{3}.$$

But the answer according to the text is $-1$.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: The text is wrong...or else it must be $\;\frac\pi3\;$ and not $\;\frac\pi6\;$ ...as in my failed attempt of answer. :)

Comment: To confirm Timbuc's comment: If $f'$ increases monotonically on $[a, b]$ from $1/\sqrt{3}$ to $1$, the integral of $f'f''$ is positive. Since the value of the integral doesn't depend on $f$ (aside from the given boundary conditions for $f'$), the answer "$-1$" cannot be correct.

Comment: Area can't be negative, it is not only mathematical term, it's an error.

Answer (score 3):

**Your solution is OK.**

My (clumsier) solution, just to reinforce yours, is as follows

We can approach the integral

$$\int_a^bf'(x)f''(x)\ dx$$
via integration by part.
The mnemonic is that $\int u'v=uv-\int uv'. $ Let $u'=f''$ and let $v=f'$. Then $u=f'$ and $v'=f''$. So

$$\int_a^b f'(x)f''(x) dx=\left[(f'(x))^2 \right]_a^b-\int_a^bf'(x)f''(x)\ dx.$$

That is,

$$\int_a^bf'(x)f''(x)dx=\frac12\left[(f'(x))^2\right]_a^b.$$

We know that $f'(a)=\tan\left(\frac{\pi}6\right)=\frac1{\sqrt3}$ and that $f'(b)=\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=1$.

Finally we get

$$\int_a^bf'(x)f''(x)dx=\frac12\left(\tan^2\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)-\tan^2\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)\right)= \frac12\left(1-\frac13\right)=\frac13\not =-1.$$